# Using sed to pattern print with specific lines

Tags: regex, sed, printing, line

```
$ cat sed-examples
```

```
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
ab
343
13524365476586o
FINEME
OKME
dasfgh
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
ab
343
13524365476586o
FINEME
OKME
dasfgh
```

i want to see the output as

```
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
FINEME
OKME
```

Tried using sed:

```
sed -n -e '/edid/ {h;n;n;n;H;x;p}h'
```

It returns:

```
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
FINEME
but not OKME
```

Comment: you need to give some more info on wanted action. ex: why not taking account line or wich to take, ... Sed is maybe not the best tool for your need.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Could you please edit your post and add the logic to get the expected output too in your post.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu from the file, i want the output as  on three lines. for some reason, am not able to put this on three lines                      
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid\n    
FINEME\n
OKME\n

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use hold-space:

```
sed -n '/edid/ { p; n; n; n; n; p; n; p; q; }' sed-examples
```

Output:

```
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
FINEME
OKME
```

Comment: Thanks Thor. however it prints only one loop, but the file it contains two iterations

Comment: @YaseenS: This was not specified in the question. Please clarify and I will amend the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Using *POSIX* `sed` (copied from [*Thor*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54946127/6136214), minus the `q`
   command):

   ```
   sed -n -e '/edid/{p;n;n;n;n;p;n;p;}' sed-examples
   ```
2. Using *GNU* `sed`:

   ```
   sed -n '1~7p;5~7p;6~7p' sed-examples
   ```

Output of either:

```
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
FINEME
OKME
this_is_a_file_to_stat_edid
FINEME
OKME
```

Comment: "~" doesnt work.
sed -n '1~7p;5~7p;6~7p' sed-examples
sed: 1: "1~7p;5~7p;6~7p": invalid command code ~

Comment: @YaseenS, This answer uses [***GNU*** `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101059/sed-behaves-different-on-freebsd-and-on-linux).  Please specify the Operating System of your system.